# How can I, scrape data from a Javascript Content of a website?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

***Actually, I am trying to fetch the content from the Product Description from the Nykaa Website.***

URL:- https://www.nykaa.com/nykaa-skinshield-matte-foundation/p/460512?productId=460512&pps=1&skuId=460502

***This is the URL, and in the section of the Product description, clicking upon the 'Read More' button, at the end there is some text.***

The **Text** which, I want to **extract** is :

> Explore the entire range of Foundation available on Nykaa. Shop more
> Nykaa Cosmetics products here.You can browse through the complete
> world of Nykaa Cosmetics Foundation . Alternatively, you can also find
> many more products from the Nykaa SkinShield Anti-Pollution Matte
> Foundation range.
>
> Expiry Date: 15 February 2024
>
> Country of Origin: India
>
> Name of Mfg / Importer / Brand: FSN E-commerce Ventures Pvt Ltd
>
> Address of Mfg / Importer / Brand: 104 Vasan Udyog Bhavan Sun Mill
> Compound Senapati Bapat Marg, Lower Parel, Mumbai City Maharashtra -
> 400013

After inspecting the page, when I, 'disable the javascript' all the content from 'product description' vanishes off. It means the content is loading dynamically with the help of Javascript.

**I have used 'selenium' for this purpose. And This, is what I have tried.**

```
from msilib.schema import Error
from tkinter import ON
from turtle import goto
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import numpy as np
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv

browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    r'C:\Users\paart\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\97.0.4692.71\chromedriver.exe')

browser.maximize_window()  # For maximizing window
browser.implicitly_wait(20)  # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds

browser.get(
    "https://www.nykaa.com/nykaa-skinshield-matte-foundation/p/460512?productId=460512&pps=1&skuId=460502")


# Creates "load more" button object.
browser.implicitly_wait(20)
loadMore = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath="/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]")

loadMore.click()
browser.implicitly_wait(20)

desc_data = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('content-details')

for desc in desc_data:
    para_details = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        './/*[@id="content-details"]/p[1]').text
    extra_details = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
        './/*[@id="content-details"]/p[2]', './/*[@id="content-details"]/p[3]', './/*[@id="content-details"]/p[4]', './/*[@id="content-details"]/p[5]').text
    print(para_details, extra_details)
```

And this, is the output which is displaying.

```
PS E:\Web Scraping - Nykaa> python -u "e:\Web Scraping - Nykaa\scrape_nykaa_final.py"
e:\Web Scraping - Nykaa\scrape_nykaa_final.py:16: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:1033/devtools/browser/097c0e11-6f2c-4742-a2b5-cd05bee72661
e:\Web Scraping - Nykaa\scrape_nykaa_final.py:28: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  loadMore = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
[9312:4972:0206/110327.883:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(996)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[9312:4972:0206/110328.019:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(996)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Web Scraping - Nykaa\scrape_nykaa_final.py", line 28, in <module>
    loadMore = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 520, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1244, in find_element    
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.99)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00FDFDC3+2555331]
        Ordinal0 [0x00F777F1+2127857]
        Ordinal0 [0x00E72E08+1060360]
        Ordinal0 [0x00E9E49E+1238174]
        Ordinal0 [0x00E9E69B+1238683]
        Ordinal0 [0x00EC9252+1413714]
        Ordinal0 [0x00EB7B54+1342292]
        Ordinal0 [0x00EC75FA+1406458]
        Ordinal0 [0x00EB7976+1341814]
        Ordinal0 [0x00E936B6+1193654]
        Ordinal0 [0x00E94546+1197382]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x01179622+1619522]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0122882C+2336844]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x010723E1+541697]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x01071443+537699]
        Ordinal0 [0x00F7D18E+2150798]
        Ordinal0 [0x00F81518+2168088]
        Ordinal0 [0x00F81660+2168416]
        Ordinal0 [0x00F8B330+2208560]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76C9FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77337A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77337A6E+238]
```

Please, anyone help me getting this issue resolved, or **any another specific piece of the code to write, which I am missing to fetch the text content from Product description**. It would be a big help.

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
from msilib.schema import Error
from tkinter import ON
from turtle import goto
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import numpy as np
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv

browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    r'C:\Users\paart\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\97.0.4692.71\chromedriver.exe')

browser.maximize_window()  # For maximizing window
browser.implicitly_wait(20)  # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds

browser.get(
    "https://www.nykaa.com/nykaa-skinshield-matte-foundation/p/460512?productId=460512&pps=1&skuId=460502")

browser.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='50%'")
time.sleep(1)
browser.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='100%'")



# Creates "load more" button object.
browser.implicitly_wait(20)
loadMore = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath='//div [@class="css-mqbsar"]')
loadMore.click()

browser.implicitly_wait(20)
desc_data = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="content-details"]/p')

# desc_data = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('content-details')
# here in your previous code this class('content-details') which is a single element so it is not iterable
# I used xpath to locate every every element <p> under the (id="content-details) attrid=bute

for desc in desc_data:
    para_detail = desc.text
    print(para_detail)

# if you you want to specify try this
#  para_detail = desc_data[0].text
#  expiry_ date = desc_data[1].text
```

and don't just copy the XPath from the chrome dev tools it's not reliable for dynamic content.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I have implemented this code, but still, the issue persists. I am getting the same error.

Comment: `
browser.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='50%'")
time.sleep(1)
browser.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='100%'")

`
add these two lines after bwowser.get this ensure the full page load

Comment: Ohh Amazing Man! Thanks a lot, you made my day.

I have added these two lines of code after, `browser.get` and it's working absolutely fine and I am also getting my desired output.

Once again, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
from msilib.schema import Error
from tkinter import ON
from turtle import goto
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import numpy as np
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv

browser = webdriver.Chrome(
r'C:\Users\paart\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\97.0.4692.71\chromedriver.exe')


browser.maximize_window()  # For maximizing window
browser.implicitly_wait(20)  # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds

browser.get(
    "https://www.nykaa.com/nykaa-skinshield-matte-foundation/p/460512?productId=460512&pps=1&skuId=460502")


# Creates "load more" button object.
browser.implicitly_wait(20)
loadMore = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]")

loadMore.click()
browser.implicitly_wait(20)

desc_data = browser.find_elements_by_id('content-details')

for desc in desc_data:
    para_details = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-details"]/p[1]').text
    expiry = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-details"]/p[2]').text
    country = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-details"]/p[3]').text
    importer = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-details"]/p[4]').text
    address = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-details"]/p[5]').text
    print(para_details, country, importer, address)
```

For the desc_data you were looking for a class name with that string, when there isn't one on the page it is actually an id tag with that string.

inside the for loop you had inserted a bunch of xpaths inside of find_elements_by_xpath() which only takes one xpath to an element.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I have implemented this code, but still, the issue persists. I am getting the same error.

Comment: @PaarthKothari the exact same error? Nothing changed? so its still failing at loadMore?

Comment: Right Sir!

The error is exactly pointing at, loadMore section.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because that element is not loaded correctly while you executed the click function.
I use these 2 function to locate elements:

```
def find_until_located(eltype,name):
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((eltype, name)))
    return element
def find_until_clicklable(eltype,name):
    element=WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((eltype, name)))
    return element
```

1st argument will be one of them: `By.ID, By.XPATH, By.LINK_TEXT, By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, By.NAME, By.TAG_NAME, By.CLASS_NAME, By.CSS_SELECTOR` and 2nd one will be your class name or xpath or id etc.
So now, your code will be:

```
from msilib.schema import Error
from tkinter import ON
from turtle import goto
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import numpy as np
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv
browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    r'C:\Users\paart\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\97.0.4692.71\chromedriver.exe')

def find_until_located(eltype,name):
    # eltype will be one of them By.ID, By.XPATH, By.LINK_TEXT, By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, By.NAME, By.TAG_NAME, By.CLASS_NAME, By.CSS_SELECTOR
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((eltype, name)))
    return element
def find_until_clicklable(eltype,name):
    element=WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((eltype, name)))
    return element

browser.maximize_window()  # For maximizing window
browser.implicitly_wait(20)  # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds

browser.get(
    "https://www.nykaa.com/nykaa-skinshield-matte-foundation/p/460512?productId=460512&pps=1&skuId=460502")



# Creates "load more" button object.
browser.implicitly_wait(20)
loadMore = find_until_clicklable(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]")
loadMore.click()
browser.implicitly_wait(20)

desc_data = browser.find_until_located(By.CLASS_NAME,'content-details')

for desc in desc_data:
    para_details = browser.find_until_located(By.XPATH,
        './/*[@id="content-details"]/p[1]').text
    extra_details = browser.find_until_located(By.XPATH,
        './/*[@id="content-details"]/p[2]', './/*[@id="content-details"]/p[3]', './/*[@id="content-details"]/p[4]', './/*[@id="content-details"]/p[5]').text
    print(para_details, extra_details)
```

### Edit:

I realised the problem and then updated the code 
 Here is the final code:

```
from msilib.schema import Error
from tkinter import ON
from turtle import goto
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import numpy as np
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv
browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    r'C:\Users\paart\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\97.0.4692.71\chromedriver.exe')

def find_until_located(eltype,name):
    # eltype will be one of them By.ID, By.XPATH, By.LINK_TEXT, By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, By.NAME, By.TAG_NAME, By.CLASS_NAME, By.CSS_SELECTOR
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((eltype, name)))
    return element
def find_until_clicklable(eltype,name):
    element=WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((eltype, name)))
    return element
def scroll_to_element(element):
        browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
        return

browser.maximize_window()  # For maximizing window
browser.implicitly_wait(20)  # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds

browser.get(
    "https://www.nykaa.com/nykaa-skinshield-matte-foundation/p/460512?productId=460512&pps=1&skuId=460502")

 

# Creates "load more" button object.
browser.implicitly_wait(20)
bag_btn=find_until_located(By.CLASS_NAME, 'css-17hv1os')
scroll_to_element(bag_btn)
desc_label=find_until_located(By.CLASS_NAME, 'css-1g43l8l')
scroll_to_element(desc_label)
# Waiting until loads
browser.implicitly_wait(20)
loadMore = find_until_clicklable(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]")
loadMore.click()
browser.implicitly_wait(20)

desc_data = find_until_located(By.ID,'content-details')

for desc in desc_data:
    para_details = find_until_located(By.XPATH,
        './/*[@id="content-details"]/p[1]').text
    extra_details = find_until_located(By.XPATH,
        './/*[@id="content-details"]/p[2]', './/*[@id="content-details"]/p[3]', './/*[@id="content-details"]/p[4]', './/*[@id="content-details"]/p[5]').text
    print(para_details, extra_details)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Tried it, But Still, my issue persists. I am not able to get the desired output. Error as shown.

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "e:\Web Scraping - Nykaa\scrape_nykaa_final_two.py", line 41, in <module> loadMore = find_until_clicklable( File "e:\Web Scraping - Nykaa\scrape_nykaa_final_two.py", line 27, in find_until_clicklable element = WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until( File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:`

Comment: @PaarthKothari I knew it. It is `TimeoutException`. and this error raises when that element is not found with in the given time. So replace `60` with `120` or `200` in those 2 functions.
Extra: I can fetch those data with javascript! Here is the code down below.
`elem=document.getElementById('content-details');para=elem.getElementsByTagName('p');for(var i=0;i<para.length;i++){alert(para[i].innerText)};`

Comment: Oh wait! I realise that the read more section visible when user focus on it. and to focus on it, we scroll down. so to scroll down, you have to execute this javascript: `document.getElementById('content-details').scrollIntoView()` before defining `loadMore` variable. and then again use `browser.implicitly_wait(20)` in your python code. so your code will be.... I uploaded this [here](https://justpaste.it/5yp6m)

Comment: I implemented the code. It was a nice explanation. But now I am facing an error in the 'execute_script'. Let me share the error part.

`selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollIntoView')`

Comment: Thanks. I have added a new function and some code to your script. I can't check that code right now. Cz I don't have selenium installed. Your code is [here](https://justpaste.it/7jof4). This time is should work. And yes, another thing to say that, you don't need to click on the read more button. because when the description loaded It contains that info you want to fetch. so just locate main div element. and you defined `content-details` as class name in in `desc_data` variable, but It is actually an ID.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented that code, which you've provided here. And, I've also updated `content-details` from `CLASS` to `ID`. But now, I'm getting an error in the `find_until_located` part which we've used in the variable named `desc_data`.

Error :- `File "e:\Web Scraping - Nykaa\scrape_nykaa_final_two.py", line 53, in <module>
    desc_data = browser.find_until_located(By.ID, 'content-details')
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_until_located'`

Comment: Thanks Brother, for your sincere efforts, finally my issue has been resolved.

Comment: Oh Sorry Again! just remove the `browser.` from that variable. It will work. I'm updating this answer for final. If you find this helpful, mark this as answer so other dude will find it easily. :)

Comment: I have implemented your updated code, But this time I'm receiving the error in `for desc in desc_data`. It's Saying that the `WebElement` object is not iterable. 

Let me share the error, for more clarity.

`File "e:\Web Scraping - Nykaa\scrape_nykaa_final_two.py", line 60, in <module>
    for desc in desc_data:
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable`

Comment: before for loop, find all p tag. example: `desc_data.find_elements_by_tag_name`. and store it in a variable. then use for loop on that variable and print(i.text). code is here, indent correctly...`tags=desc_data.find_elements_by_tag_name('p') for i in tags: print(i.text)`.... this should work

Answer (score 0):

***Final Answer - To this Question.***

```
from msilib.schema import Error
from tkinter import ON
from turtle import goto
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import numpy as np
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv

browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    r'C:\Users\paart\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\97.0.4692.71\chromedriver.exe')


browser.maximize_window()  # For maximizing window
browser.implicitly_wait(20)  # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds

# browser.get(
#     "https://www.nykaa.com/nykaa-skinshield-matte-foundation/p/460512?productId=460512&pps=1&skuId=460502")

browser.get(
    "https://www.nykaa.com/kay-beauty-hydrating-foundation/p/1229442?productId=1229442&pps=3&skuId=772975")

browser.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='50%'")
browser.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='100%'")


# Creates "load more" button object.
browser.implicitly_wait(20)
loadMore = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]")

loadMore.click()
browser.implicitly_wait(20)

desc_data = browser.find_elements(By.ID, 'content-details')

for desc in desc_data:
    para_details = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                        '//*[@id="content-details"]/p[1]').text
    expiry = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                  '//*[@id="content-details"]/p[2]').text
    country = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                   '//*[@id="content-details"]/p[3]').text
    importer = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                    '//*[@id="content-details"]/p[4]').text
    address = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                   '//*[@id="content-details"]/p[5]').text
    # print(para_details, country, importer, address)
    print(f"{para_details} \n")
    print(f"{expiry} \n")
    print(f"{country} \n")
    print(f"{importer} \n")
    print(f"{address} \n")
```